Cannot build Micronaut project using gradle
I cannot build my project in micronaut using gradle's command ./gradlew build because it failed with error. I added whole log on the end. I thought that error is because of following line [WARN] Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: io.micronaut.annotation.processing.TypeElementVisitorProcessor (DYNAMIC). 
But I found out that when I will build some services with skipped tests then they are successfully built with same warning message.
I also tried change memory to 4096 in Help -> Change Memory settings but it doesn't help.
Gradle's version prints following:
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.6
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-11-25 13:35:10 UTC
Revision:     daece9dbc5b79370cc8e4fd6fe4b2cd400e150a8

Kotlin:       1.7.10
Groovy:       3.0.13
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          11.0.23 (Eclipse Adoptium 11.0.23+9)
OS:           Mac OS X 14.5 aarch64

Whole log:
> Task :service:kaptKotlin
[WARN] Issue detected with io.micronaut.annotation.processing.TypeElementVisitorProcessor. Expected 1 originating source file when generating /Users/xxxx/Work/foo-service/service/build/generated/source/kapt/main/dummy588074428538458, but detected 0: [].
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "Daemon client event forwarder" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.addConditionWaiter(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1896)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2114)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:458)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonConnectionBackedEventConsumer$ForwardEvents.getNextEvent(DaemonConnectionBackedEventConsumer.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonConnectionBackedEventConsumer$ForwardEvents.run(DaemonConnectionBackedEventConsumer.java:59)
Error while receiving file changes
net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Caught java.lang.OutOfMemoryError with message: Java heap space
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.jni.AbstractNativeFileEventFunctions$NativeFileWatcher.executeRunLoop0(Native Method)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.jni.AbstractNativeFileEventFunctions$NativeFileWatcher.executeRunLoop(AbstractNativeFileEventFunctions.java:42)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.jni.AbstractFileEventFunctions$AbstractFileWatcher$1.run(AbstractFileEventFunctions.java:154)
45 actionable tasks: 45 executed

> Task :service:kaptKotlin FAILED
Note: Generating OpenAPI Documentation

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Gradle build daemon has been stopped: JVM garbage collector thrashing and after running out of JVM memory

EDIT:
I have 64GB RAM so I set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS to -Xms512m -Xmx48g but it didn't help.

when I will build some services with skipped tests then they are successfully built ... Time to look at the tests, and see if there is any recursive memory leak

This built was random, because I tried at again later with tests and they build fine.
